# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell.getRowspan()I

Tags: java, velocity

Getting Above issue while Generating PDF from DOCX , and creating Dynamic table and getting this error in "PdfConverter.getInstance()"

```
    InputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-In.docx"));
    IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

    FieldsMetadata metadata = report.createFieldsMetadata();

    metadata.load("details", Detail.class, true );

    IContext context = report.createContext();

    Project project = null;
    project = new Project("XDocReport-3","Hello Belong Mobile 1");
    context.put("project", project);

    List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();
    for(int x=0;x<5;x++)
    {
        details.add(new Detail("ABC "+x, "XYZ", "ABC.XYZ@gmail.com"));
    }
    context.put("details", details);


    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-Out.docx"));
    report.process(context, out);

    InputStream pdf = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-In-1.docx"));
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(pdf);
    PdfOptions options = null;//PdfOptions.create();
    OutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-Out-1.pdf"));
    PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out2, options);
```

Comment: Add your code and stacktrace, please

Comment: InputStream pdf = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-In-1.docx"));
         XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(pdf);
         PdfOptions options = null;//PdfOptions.create();
         OutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\XDocReports\\sample-Out-1.pdf"));
         PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out2, options);

Comment: As an [edit] to your post, please

Comment: Also, typically you get such an error when you've compiled the wrong version of the library you need

Comment: tried to find library with "getRowspan()" method but not able to do that

Comment: You didn't search correctly, then... http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html

Comment: Done its working fine after putting proper iText version in Lib

Comment: Cool. Note: you'd be better off using Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies